# defining multiple parameters in python as one variable

Tags: python

I have over 100 different parameters that will be tested against a single variable. But I am having trouble assigned the parameters as variables. For example: The parameters are as follows:

```
/master.passwd
etc/passwd
etc/shadow%00
/etc/passwd
/etc/passwd%00
../etc/passwd
../etc/passwd%00
../../etc/passwd
../../etc/passwd%00
```

and each parameter will be added to a variable named

```
tree
```

How can I use python to assign one variable to 100's of parameters and than add each parameter to the variable named *tree*? I have looked at list[], dict{}, and a tuple() but I am not coming up with a solution.

[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB4q9.png)

Comment: The best data type to use depends on what you're going to do with the data. How are you going to use it, modify it, relate it to other data or itself, output it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to iterate over a bunch of strings and do something with them? One way of doing this is to use a list:

```
url='https://10.10.20.161/IHUD/'
parameters = ["master.passwd",
    "etc/passwd",
    "etc/shadow%00",
    "/etc/passwd",
    "/etc/passwd%00",
    "../etc/passwd",
    "../etc/passwd%00",
    "../../etc/passwd",
    "../../etc/passwd%00"]

for p in parameters:
    tree = url + p
    print(tree)
```

Outputs:

```
https://10.10.20.161/IHUD/master.passwd
https://10.10.20.161/IHUD/etc/passwd
https://10.10.20.161/IHUD/etc/shadow%00
https://10.10.20.161/IHUD//etc/passwd
https://10.10.20.161/IHUD//etc/passwd%00
https://10.10.20.161/IHUD/../etc/passwd
https://10.10.20.161/IHUD/../etc/passwd%00
https://10.10.20.161/IHUD/../../etc/passwd
https://10.10.20.161/IHUD/../../etc/passwd%00
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to iterate over a bunch of strings but the problem with the list[] I am getting the output with a bunch of '' attached to my strings as show ['master.passwd', 'etc/passwd', 'etc/shadow%00', '/etc/passwd', '/etc/passwd%00', '../etc/passwd', '../etc/passwd%00', '../../etc/passwd', '../../etc/passwd%00'] @Galax

Comment: If you write `print(parameters)` you'll see something like:

`['master.passwd', 'etc/passwd', 'etc/shadow%00', '/etc/passwd', '/etc/passwd%00', '../etc/passwd', '../etc/passwd%00', '../../etc/passwd', '../../etc/passwd%00']`

Can you show the code you are using as it may help to explain the problem you are having a little better.

Comment: I just added a screenshot to my question @Galax. So after I have defined the parameter to the variable tree, the output format needs to look like: url + tree https://10.10.20.161/IHUD/etc/passwd for each parameter

Comment: I've updated my code, the problem with your screenshot is that `str(parameters)` converts the list to a string representation of a list, with all the `[`, and `'`.

Comment: I see now! So p can be seen as a variable in the list parameters defining each parameter in the list? I just want to make sure my interpretation is right.

Comment: Yes the `for x in y` statement is very useful for iterating over a sequence (list, set, dictionary, etc.) `y`, with `x` set to be the value of each element in the sequence on each iteration.